# Client Not loading Fresh content in IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, caching, iframe, iis-7.5

We have asp.net 4.0 web site hosted on IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. The problem is that client is getting old content but server have updated copies. Client needs to press Ctrl+F5 every time to get the latest contents. Even in the case of data update on grids, client still get old data shown in IFRAME.

What could be the reasons?? Any Idea?? Is this a problem of Cache??

Any kind of assistance will be appreciated..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page output caching stores a response of a dynamic page, such as an ASP page or an ASP.NET page, in memory after a browser requests it. When subsequent requests arrive for the page, the server sends the cached response instead of re-processing the page.

Check this article, it may be helpful for you.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/caching

These links will also help you

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/710/configure-iis-7-output-caching/

https://serverfault.com/questions/126914/output-caching-with-iis7-how-to-for-an-dynamic-aspx-page

[IIS7: set "no-cache" for all aspx pages but not images/css/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022960/iis7-set-no-cache-for-all-aspx-pages-but-not-images-css-js)

https://superuser.com/questions/63014/how-do-i-turn-off-caching-in-iis7

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using Chrome Developer Tool viewing source code of Html file hosted on IIS, when I modify the html file and refresh IIS site, the source code show in chrome wasn't modified after refresh the browser.

In the beginning I guess it's IIS caching, but after I try the link in other answer, it didn't really work: https://superuser.com/questions/63014/how-do-i-turn-off-caching-in-iis7

Finally I go to Chrome Setting and clear the Chrome File Cache, the html source code successfully changed. So in my case it is caused by Chrome's Cache, hope it help someone.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I found, there is an HTTPCompression setting that may have sendCacheHeading set to true.
  I found this in the applicationHost.config file and changed it there but it can be changed in IIS also by using the Configuration Editor.

Example:

[image: Example]

If you want to change this through IIS select Configuration Editor then click the dropdown arrow at the top and expand system.webserver then select httpCompression.

Per Laurenz request I have copied the text version of what I found in the config file and what I changed it to:

Original:
<httpCompression sendCacheHeaders="true" directory="C:\Windows\IIS Temporary Compressed Files" maxDiskSpaceUsage="1000000" noCompressionForProxies="false" noCompressionForRange="true">

Changed to:
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">

Comment: It would be better to use text that can be copied an pasted than an image.